# Relationship in EF Core by ID and Type

Tags: entity-framework-core, relational-database

I use EF Core (Code first) I need to make relation between 2 tables by ID and Type
the following are my classes

```
    public class Lead : BaseEntity
    {
   

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public short Status { get; set; }

    public short PhoneType { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public short EmailType { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
 
    public List<AddressInformation> AddressInformations { get; set; }

    }


    public class Opportunity : BaseEntity
    {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<AddressInformation> AddressInformations { get; set; }
   }

    public class AddressInformationViewModel
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int SourceID { get; set; }  // in this column i need to store ID for Lead or Oppurtunity
    public string RelatedTo { get; set; } // in this column i need to store text "Lead" or "Oppurtunity"
    public short AddresType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

> The AddressInformation class will hold information for Leads or Opportunity based on SourceID and RelatedTo columns

how we can handle this relation?
when I make Data Migrations EF will add new column in Lead Table the column name "LeadID" and I don't need this approach, is there any way to handle like this relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest considering a many-to-many joining table for each relationship rather than effectively a SourceId + SourceType association within Address. I.e. using a LeadAddress table and an OpportunityAddress table. With EF Core 5 and EF 6 you can associate these without a joining entity, just mapping the joining table, or create a joining entity for earlier EF Core, or if you need additional columns in the relationship.

The main advantage of using specific linking tables is that you can maintain FK relationships. With a SourceId + SourceType you cannot use SourceId as a FK to both Lead and Opportunity, however with a joining table, the LeadId can FK to lead while AddressId can FK to address. This helps keep querying address related details efficient.

A benefit, or limitation of this approach to consider is that with linking tables an address can legally be assigned to both a Lead and an Opportunity, or shared between Leads /Opportunities. If you don't want to support addresses being shared across multiple entities you would need to implement checks to prevent it. This does mean treating an address as a distinct location rather than merely a data container for a particular related entity. For example 123 Smithe St. is always 123 Smithe St. To change an address for a Lead would typically mean associating it with a new Address object with different values rather than editing the values of 123 Smithe St. (Unless they actually mean to correct the address, I.e. 123 Smith St.)

SourceId + SourceType can be implemented, but AFAIK this would have to be handled as separate unrelated entities and joined manually with queries, I.e. something like:

```
var query = context.Leads
    .Join(context.Addresses.Where(a => a.RelatedTo == "lead"),
        l => l.Id,
        a => a.SourceId,
        (l,a) => new {Lead = l, Addresses = a})
    .Single(x => x.Lead.Id == leadId);
```

As queries get more involved this gets more complex to deal with the Join, and AFAIK you won't get something as useful as lead.Addresses out of the mapping/navigation properties where you can have lead.Addresses or at least lead.LeadAddresses using the dedicated linking table.

Comment: Thanks Steven, Good answer but i tell you Lead and opportunity as current but may be in future I will need another entity like customers and contacts etc.. and I need to connect theme with AddressInformation. the number of classes will be more.